# How to set the Presentations pagsize in PowerPoint using C# interop library?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

How to set  the  Presentations or slide(PPT) pagsize  in PowerPoint using C# interop library?

I want to set the  Presentations  pagsize is  "**ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9**"

```
     // Create new Slide
        PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
        MyPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        MyPres.Final = false;
        MyPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = PowerPoint.PpSlideSizeType.ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9;

        Code more ...
```

This result is not what I expected ;
 Now, how to set the Presentations or slide(PPT) pagsize?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it's how I've been setting the slide size.

```
this.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight = <your slide height>;
this.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth = <your slide width>;
```

Allows you to set the width and height of the slide in points, not pixels. You can use the below to convert pixels to points

```
private int PixelsToPoints(int pixels)
{
     return pixels * 72 / 96;
}
```

Comment: Try running your code.  the  error msg is  "    Invalid request. There is no active presentation."  why??

Comment: Have you tried the code after creating a presentation? I'm running it when a presentation has been created, and a slide is visible. It then adjusts the size of the slide, and subsequent slides

Comment: @Sandwich   Thanks for your help, I found the problem, it is this line of code can not achieve the desired effect, I changed the other way

Comment: @Sandwich Could you please mention where the "72" value comes from? What's the point of it?

Answer (score 0):

now,this is right code:

```
        PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
        MyPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        MyPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth = <slide width>;
        MyPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight = <slide height >;
```

This line of code have bug?, I'm not sure !!

```
        MyPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = PowerPoint.PpSlideSizeType.ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9;
```